# Aggregate and calculate values in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with some incoming and outgoing data.

```
+====+===========+==========+============+
| id | flow(int) | quantity | product_id |
+====+===========+==========+============+
| 1  | 0         | 100      | 1          |
+----+-----------+----------+------------+
| 2  | 1         | 20       | 1          |
+----+-----------+----------+------------+
| 3  | 1         | 30       | 1          |
+----+-----------+----------+------------+
| 4  | 0         | 10       | 1          |
+----+-----------+----------+------------+
| 5  | 1         | 30       | 2          |
+----+-----------+----------+------------+
| 6  | 2         | 10       | 2          |
+----+-----------+----------+------------+
| 7  | 0         | 10       | 2          |
+====+===========+==========+============+
```

Column flow is a type of enum, 0 - incoming, 1 and 2 - outgoing operation.

How can I get current "balance" of specific product?

Product 1 should have "balance" 60 = incoming(100) - outgoing(20) - outgoing(30) + incoming(10).

And Product 2 should have -30 "balance" = outgoing(30) - outgoing(10) - incoming(10).

Is is possible to make in any efficient way with single query?

Comment: Add some more sample table data (e.g. another product). Also specify the expected result set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following:

```
SELECT product_id,
       SUM( IF(flow IN ('1','2'), 
               -1*quantity, 
               quantity) ) AS balance
FROM table_name
GROUP BY product_id;
```

Comment: SELECT product_id, SUM( IF(flow=0, quantity,(-1*quantity)) ) AS balance
FROM table_name
GROUP BY product_id;

Comment: If (false) or if (!true) are same things only. So if condition can be varied keeping logic same

Answer (score 1):

This would be conditional aggregation:

```
select product_id,
       sum(case when flow like 'out_%' then - quantity else quantity end) as net_quantity
from t
group by product_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
With incoming_product as(
   select product_id,sum(quantity) res
   from my_table
   where flow = 0
   group by product_id
),
outgoing_product as(
   select product_id,sum(quantity) res
   from my_table
   where flow <> 0
   group by product_id
)
select t1.product_id, t1.res - t2.res
from incoming_product t1,outgoing_product t2
where t1.product_id = t2.product_id;
```

Comment: is it more efficient than sum..if?

Comment: He didn't specifie his sgbd.